# Is there a standard for line break characters in web forms?

Tags: newline, web-standards, carriage-return

Can I expect line breaks in text boxes to be one of the common line break conventions or does it depend on the user's OS?

i.e.: CR or CR+LF or LF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [HTML 4.01 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) states that line breaks are represented as CR LF pairs.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the language. usually in .NET you would use

```
Environment.NewLine
```

in JavaScript it would be "/n"

in VbScript you could use  "vbNewLine"

Comment: minor typo: in JS, newline is `\n` not `/n`

Comment: I'm aware, thanks, but the language I process it with has no effect on what data the web form sends. I'm also fairly certain that almost all language constants [in this context] are only provided to make source code portable.